# Is it safe to use Grub on an existing Win10 Machine?

Tags: dual-boot

I have a laptop an desktop that both have Win10 on them and I was going to add Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit on a side by side install. I've seen lots of issues with machines that already had Ubuntu installed alongside Win 7 or 8, that showed up when attempting to upgrade to Win10.

I have not seen anything about problems of adding Ubuntu with Grub to an existing Win10 machine. Any dangers in doing this?

Comment: Just be sure to install in UEFI boot mode. What brand/model systems?  Use Windows to shrink Windows NTFS partition and reboot so it runs chkdsk. Make sure fast start up is off in Windows and fast boot is off in UEFI. Usually best to have Secure boot off. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 8 screens (Windows 10 should be same)
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 3):

There is always a slight risk when dealing with partitions on a disk, and there is always that risk that you could corrupt your drive.

However, it will most likely work fine. The 15.04 installer has an <kbd>Install alongside Windows</kbd> option built-in, which means you may not even need to mess around with partition tables:

[image]

If you don't want to risk anything, I would suggest booting the CD/DVD/USB and using <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd> and see if you're happy with it before installing.

So in summary: YES there are dangers, but if you don't do anything, you cannot do anything wrong either (nor anything right).

Comment: Yes 14.04has the same alongside feature. My question is: Is there something particularly strange about win10 itself that would cause a problem with the 14.04  dual boot install, which might result in either O/S being corrupted?

Comment: Nope. I have windows 10, and ubuntu! No problems at all!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, someone who actually has them installed, side by side. I will try it on my Core I3 with 8 gB ram, as soon as I have time. I have the install on both a USB stick and a bootable DVD. When I get it done, I'll post some feedback.

Comment: Well I'm glad I could help.. Because you are new to Ask Ubuntu, if this answer helped you please push the checkmark next to this answer to say "Yes this answer was helpful" thanks, have a great day!